# Is it bad proactive to create backing subclasses for your layouts if they don't need customization?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-layout

I'm new to Android and have recently started adopting the pattern to create an auto-layout-loading custom view based on a layout file.  In the layout you use the 'merge' tag as the root, then in the constructor of your view, you inflate that layout into yourself so you are essentially the root of the merged-in controls.  Right after you inflate, still in the constructor, you can find the child controls from the layout and assign them to private fields in the custom class so they will always be available, even when using recycler views.

Contrast that with including a layout.  In that case, the layout has to define a root element (which can be your custom control, but in that case, you would *not* inflate the layout into yourself and would have to move the control lookup to onFinishInflate) but otherwise it ends up with the same view hierarchy.

In short, instead of this...

```
<include layout="@layout/layout_myCustomControl" />
```

You can now do this...

```
<com.mydomain.MyCustomControl />
```

However I find the auto-loading custom control version to be much more flexible and maintainable.  The advantages of the second one are not only that you can use custom attributes in the referencing XML layouts (which you can't with the 'include' version) but it also gives you a central place to manage the code as well as layout management/control lookup.

So now I can do this...

```
<com.mydomain.MyCustomControl
    app:myCustomAttribute="Foo" />
```

And if the control has to have code backing up its behavior, it's nicely encapsulated in the custom view.

Here's an example layout for the auto-loading version...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is static text in the header" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

And here's the class that uses it...

```
public class MainHeader extends LinearLayout
{
    TextView dateTextView;

    public MainHeader(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header_main, this);

        dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);

        dateTextView.setText(<<Code for setting date goes here>>);
    }
}
```

But what I'm wondering is if the layout is purely static in nature--say holding a static image and fixed text--is it still considered good practice to use a custom view to represent it?  I'd say yes for consistency, plus should I want to extend it in the future, you're already prepared for it and have to do so in just one place regardless of how many places it's used.  In contrast, if you included the layout directly in say 20 places, you may have to update all 20 (depending on what's actually changed/needed.)

Pros for the Custom View approach:

1. Central location for managing layout loading and control lookup
2. Can support backing code implicitly/internally for updating the view.
3. Can use attributes when being referenced in other layout files
4. Better encapsulation (you can hide the layout itself from the outside world exposing behaviors via direct methods)
5. Can simply be 'new'd' up in code and the layout will automatically load. No inflating or casting needed.

Cons for Custom View approach

1. When used in Layout files, you now have to also specify width and height making usage a little more verbose.
2. May add extra classes to your project (not always, but sometimes.)

Again, it seems to me like a no-brainer, but I'm wondering if there's a preferred 'Androidy' way, or is it just a preference up to each developer?

Comment: Well, if you add something you don't use... just don't add it. It would only introduce overhead, don't you agree?

Comment: But as an example, we have a standard footer which is just a block of static text.  Even if that text ever changes, we of course could simply update the layout.  But now, what if they want to add a 'Content recent as of mm-dd-yyyy' to the footer?  That's something that we don't need now, but having it as a control, not just a layout, would make adding that trivial, even when used in other packages.

Comment: Contrast that to propagating the layout.  Now everywhere you're using it, you'd have to do work in the Java class to find that layout first, then the relevant TextView and update it. But you may still have to go back and add IDs to your includes too.  That's why I like the control idea, and realistically, how often do you use purely static layouts?  Isn't planning ahead good?

Comment: It really depends. I never had such a need, if I didn't plan it at design time.  Maybe you are just overthinking.

Answer (score 0):

Such approach will add additional level in your view trees. So you only made the UI tree more complex for no good reason. From other side, you can follow next steps to get rid of that side-effect:

1. `<merge />` can only be used as the root tag of an XML layout
2. when inflating a layout starting with a `<merge />`, you must specify a parent 
   `ViewGroup` and you must set `attachToRoot` to `true` (see the
   documentation of the [inflate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) method)

That's it.

Comment: Actually, your statement is incorrect. This doesn't add anything else to the view tree.  In the 'include' case, you define the root element in the layout whereas in the custom view case as I stated (which also is in the documentation you linked to), you use the merge tag as the root in the layout, then inflate into yourself in the constructor (so you become the root).  Again, there are no additional views in the view tree.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently what I came up with wasn't that unique after all!  Here's an article explaining in detail this exact scenario, along with the pros and cons of each.  Looks like they too came to the same conclusion.

[TrickyAndroid: Protip. Inflating layout for your custom view](http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/)